# GRAILS GORM : eager fetch in cascading style

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to eager fetch a record in cascading style(deep style fetching)?

Example:

I have Domain class A,B,C .

where all domain objects have many-to-many relation with each other(a bit of exaggeration)

my goal is to fetch all relations eagerly by using ->

```
A.list()
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what you are looking to do? Perhaps post your Domain classes and how they relate? Otherwise just search for `fetch mode grails query` on Google because your question is so broad it can not be answered here.

Comment: fetch the entire object(eagrly) and dependencies from database, so it always succeeds (unless a loop is present), without specifying which dependencies to fetch, thus... i call it `fetch all\fetch deep`

Answer (score 0):

You could replace list() with CreateCriteria() and explicitly define which relations should be loaded eagerly. Just mention relation in the query.

Grails example:

```
def c = Teacher.createCriteria()

List<Teacher> results = c.list {
            subjects {
                attendees {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: this works, but i don't wish to specify which property to eager fetch, i wish to fetch all dependencies.

Comment: I think there are only two options:

1. specify fetch type for relations in the domain class (any access to the object will load whole tree then)
2. specify particular property in Criteria (as I already suggested)